# Joining 4 SQL Tables, 3 Sources one 'container'

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables, Activities, Users, Locations.

Activities has columns ID (autoincrement) and activity name (varchar 40).

Users has ID and name

Locations has ID and coordString

A fourth table exists with columns activityID, userID, userActivityID. The purpose of this table is to link up the ids where the user has selected activities relevant to them. userActivityID is then a new ID to link to this 'relevant' object.

How do i go about doing this? Would anyone suggest a more sensible data structure?

Thank you all as always.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you know how `INNER JOIN` works? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx

Comment: I tried INNER JOIN but I had royally buggered up the syntax. Thanks for the post though:D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need INNER JOIN and this should go something like this (link_table is used since you did not give name of the table):

```
SELECT activities.*, users.*, locations.* 
FROM activities, users, locations, link_table 
WHERE activities.id = link_table.activityID
AND users.id = link_table.userID
AND locations.id = link_table.locationID
```

or you can also write it like this:

```
SELECT activities.*, users.*, locations.* 
FROM link_table
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = link_table.userID
INNER JOIN locations ON locations.id = link_table.locationID
INNER JOIN activities ON activities.id = link_table.activityID
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry i forgot the table name of the fourth table xD

You've saved my hair. *hands a beer*

Comment: An accepted answer is quite enough, especially since I don't drink alcohol :)

Comment: Ah sorry, well in that case have a coffee or beverage of your choosing! Their should be a donate button on stackoverflow!